# Do the Pre-cogs detect suicides?

Tags: minority-report

Leo Crow essentially commits suicide in the movie. This is contrary to what the pre-cogs predicted, but it is a death of passion. If Agatha had been in the temple, would the pre-cogs have created a brown ball for this passionate death, which was essentially self inflicted?

Comment: They did see Crow's murder. However, Anderton chooses not to go through with it at the last moment, thus invalidating the whole science behind pre-crime. Crow's blackmail by Burgess was just insurance so that framing of Anderton would still look authentic (since Burgess knows that pre-crime is fallible.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No, they don't detect suicides.

From the [original script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/MINORITY_REPORT_--_May_16th_2001_revised_draft_by_Scott_Frank.html) by Scott Frank

> **ANDERTON :** *The Precogs don't see what you intend to do, only what you will do.*
>
> **WITWER :** *Then why can't they see rapes, or assaults... or suicides?*
>
> **FLETCHER :** *Because of the nature of murder.*